# Extracting meaningful information from stacktrace

Tags: java

How can we get meaningful information from stack trace generated, eg the stack trace generated by following catch block

```
try{


}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Kindly reply.Thanks in advance.

Comment: it depends of what is meaningful to you

Comment: It displays all the information in the Exception. Is the problem that you want to know how to read the stack trace?

Comment: @Peter:yes you are rite.could you please guide me a little bit?

Comment: Witha quick google I found these would look useful http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip124.html http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good answer I found in another forum regarding this. Read [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t71267-understanding-the-stack-trace.html), then [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/) and definitely [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip124.html).

Answer (score 1):

I find the following pieces of the stack trace meaningful:

1. The line in your own class where the exception occurred: this will give you an indication if you're possibly making a mistake, e.g. incorrect pre-conditions or usage of a 3rd party API.
2. The root cause (in the case of nested exceptions): e.g. you're trying to connect to a database on a non-existent remote server -- the exception will be some SqlException, but the root cause will point to an incorrect host name, for instance.